# Single model different view and CRUD functionality in RubyOnRails3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

As a new to Ruby on rails, I stumble on a part of my app. I read the basics of RoR framework and know the 'convention over configuration' feature of rails MVC. I have two tables, one is **apps_events** and another is **apps_events_attributes**. The id of the first one is the foreign key of the second and in has many relationship. The app_events table has a field of foreign key attribute 'app_id', so selecting on a particular app I will be redirected to its events and attributes. There is also a field called 'is_standard' which actually distinguish the event type whether it's a *Standard* or *Custom* event.

Now I have to render those events and its attributes of a particular app in two different tab on the view layer with it's attributes using nested_form_for feature. User can toggle to Standard and Custom event through this tab click. Can anyone suggest me how will I achieve the same and can show me the ideal flow of this scenario (model name and checking part of 'is_standard', propagate the same in controller and render to the view)?

By the way, can I use different controller over the same model and if I do the same then is it capable of doing the same CRUD functionality for different Event and its attributes?

Comment: Add some code for the models and views to better explain your question, walls of text can be off-putting to would-be responders.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have all it done alone and it is not very hard what I think at first, all trick is done by **JQuery**... and share the concept if somebody got same problem as me

My **Models** are

```
class AppsEvent < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :app
  has_many :apps_events_attributes, :foreign_key => 'apps_event_id',
       :class_name => 'AppsEventsAttribute',
       :dependent => :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :apps_events_attributes,
                            :reject_if => lambda { |a| (a[:name].blank? &&    a[:description].blank?) },
                            :allow_destroy => true
  validates_presence_of :description
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_presence_of :code
  validates_presence_of :apps_events_attributes, :message => "can't be empty"
end
```

and

```
class AppsEventsAttribute < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table_name :apps_events_attributes
  belongs_to :apps_event, :foreign_key => 'apps_event_id'
  attr_accessible :id, :apps_event_id, :name, :description, :attribute_type, :is_std, :created_at, :updated_at

  def type
    self.attribute_type
  end
end
```

and My **Controller** is...

```
class AppsEventsController < ApplicationController
  layout :layout_by_resource
  before_filter :initialize_default_app
  before_filter :check_permission
  before_filter :load

  def load
    @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])
    @apps_events = AppsEvent.where(:app_id => @app.id)
    @apps_event = AppsEvent.new
  end

  def index
    @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])
    @default_app = App.default(current_user)
    @apps_events = AppsEvent.where(:app_id => @app.id)
    @apps_event_jsons = Hash.new
    @apps_events.each do |app_event|
      json = Hash.new
      json['User_ID'] = 548741213
      json['Session_ID'] = 2568639390
      json['Action_Type'] = app_event.code
      json['eventsData'] = {}

      app_event.apps_events_attributes.each do |apps_event_attributes|
        if (apps_event_attributes.attribute_type == 'Integer')
          json['eventsData'][apps_event_attributes.name] = 1234
        elsif (apps_event_attributes.attribute_type == 'Float')
          json['eventsData'][apps_event_attributes.name] = 1234.23
        else
          json['eventsData'][apps_event_attributes.name] = 'abcd'
        end
      end

      @apps_event_jsons[app_event.id] = json
    end
  end

  def new
    @apps_event = AppsEvent.new
    @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])
    @apps_event.app_id = @app.id
    @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.build
    @action = 'create'
    render 'edit'
  end

  def edit
    @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])
    @apps_event = AppsEvent.find(params[:id])
    @action = 'update'
  end

  def create
    @apps_event = AppsEvent.new(params[:apps_event])
    @show_custom_event = 'true'
    @apps_event.name = @apps_event.name.strip
    respond_to do |format|
      if @apps_event.save
        format.html {
          redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                  :notice => "Successfully created #{@apps_event.name} custom definition.")
        }
        format.js {
          flash[:notice] = 'Successfully created event.'
          @apps_events = AppsEvent.where(:app_id => @app.id)
        }
      else
        @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])

        if (@apps_event.apps_events_attributes == nil ||   @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.size <= 0)
          @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.build
        end

        @apps_event.populate_code
        @action = 'create'
        format.html {
          redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                  :alert => "Error in creating #{@apps_event.name} custom definition.")
        }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def update
    @apps_event = AppsEvent.find(params[:apps_event][:id])
    params[:apps_event][:name] = params[:apps_event][:name].strip

    respond_to do |format|
      if @apps_event.update_attributes(params[:apps_event])
        format.html {
          if(@apps_event.is_std == 'y')
            redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                  :notice => "Successfully updated #{@apps_event.name} standard definition.")
          else
            redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                    :notice => "Successfully updated #{@apps_event.name} custom definition.")
          end
        }
        format.js {
          flash[:notice] = 'Successfully updated event.'
          @apps_events = AppsEvent.where(:app_id => @app.id)
          render :nothing => true
        }
      else
        @app = current_user.find_app(params[:app_id])

        if (@apps_event.apps_events_attributes == nil || @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.size <= 0)
          @apps_event.apps_events_attributes.build
        end

        @apps_event.populate_code
        @action = "update"
        format.html {
          if(@apps_event.is_std == 'y')
            redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                  :alert => "Error in updating #{@apps_event.name} standard definition.")
          else
            redirect_to("/app/#{params[:apps_event][:app_id]}/apps_events",
                    :alert => "Error in updating #{@apps_event.name} custom definition.")
          end
        }
        format.js
      end
    end
  end

  def delete
    if AppsEvent.delete(params[:id])
      redirect_to "/app/#{params[:app_id]}/apps_events", :notice => "Successfully deleted #{@apps_event.name} custom definition."
    else
      redirect_to "/app/#{params[:app_id]}/apps_events",
              :alert => "Error in deleting #{@apps_event.name} custom definition."
    end
  end
end
```

and I have 5 view files which are index.html.erb, edit.js.erb, _form_custom.html.erb, _form_standard.html.erb and _events.html.erb beside that have also a helper file for update, create and delete using ajax call by setting remote => true. In index file I am doing partial rendering all events(_events.html.erb) and here I done the trick :P
My **_events.html.erb**

```
<% for apps_event in @apps_events %>
  <% if (apps_event.is_std == 'y') %>
    <div class="standardEvent showStandard">
      <ul>
        <li class="column_1"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><%= apps_event.name %></span></li>
        <li class="column_2"><span><%= apps_event.code %></span></li>
        <li class="column_3"><span><%= apps_event.description %></span></li>
        <li class="column_4">
          <%= link_to edit_apps_event(apps_event) %>
        </li>
        <li class="column_5">

        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="customEvent showCustom" style="display:none">
      <ul>
        <li class="column_1"><span style="font-weight: bold;"><%= apps_event.name %></span></li>
        <li class="column_2"><span><%= apps_event.code %></span></li>
        <li class="column_3"><span><%= apps_event.description %></span></li>
        <li class="column_4">
          <%= link_to edit_apps_event(apps_event) %>
        </li>
        <li class="column_5">
          <%= remove_apps_event_prompt_link(apps_event) %>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="clrBoth"></div>
<% end %>
```

now you can figure out the left part mean -- JQuery part to hide or show a div.